# R shiny isolate reactive data.frame

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

I am struggling to understand how `isolate()` and `reactive()` should be used in R Shiny.

I want to achieve the following:

Whenever the "Refresh" action button is clicked:

- Perform a `subset` on a data.frame and,
- Feed this into my function to recalculate values.

The subset depends on a group of checkboxes that the user has ticked, of which there are approximately 40. I cannot have these checkboxes "fully reactive" because the function takes about 1.5 sec to execute. Instead, I want to give the user a chance to select multiple boxes and only afterwards click a button to (a) subset and (b) call the function again.

To do so, I load the data.frame in the server.R function:

```
df1 <- readRDS("D:/././df1.RData")
```

Then I have my main shinyServer function:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data_output <- reactive({
    df1 <- df1[,df1$Students %in% input$students_selected] 

    #Here I want to isolate the "students_selected" so that this is only 
    #executed once the button is clicked
  })

  output$SAT <- renderTable({
    myFunction(df1)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like

```
data_output <- eventReactive(input$button, {
    df1[,df1$Students %in% input$students_selected] 
})
```

Here is my minimal example.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- list(sliderInput("num", "rowUpto", min= 1, max = 10, value = 5), 
           actionButton("btn", "update"),
           tableOutput("tbl")) 
server <- function(input, output) {
  data_output <- eventReactive(input$btn, {
    data.frame(id = 1:10, x = 11:20)[seq(input$num), ]
  })

  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    data_output()})
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

**Edit**

Another implementation, a bit more concise.
`renderTable` by default inspects the changes in all reactive elements within the function (in this case, `input$num` and `input$button`).
But, you want it to react only to the button.  Hence you need to put the elements to be ignored within the `isolate` function.
If you omit the `isolate` function, then the table is updated as soon as the slider is moved.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- list(sliderInput("num", "rowUpto", min= 1, max = 10, value = 5), 
           actionButton("btn", "update"),
           tableOutput("tbl")) 
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    input$btn
    data.frame(id = 1:10, x = 11:20)[seq(isolate(input$num)), ]
  })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: Yes, ```eventReactive``` is triggered when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

Use `eventReactive` instead:

```
data_output <- eventReactive(input$updateButton, {

    df1 <- df1[,df1$Students %in% input$students_selected] #I think your comments are messed up here, but I'll leave the filtering formatting to you

  })

  output$SAT <- renderTable({
    data_output()
  })
```

And in your UI you should have something like:

```
actionButton('updateButton',label = "Filter")
```

Looking at ?shiny::eventReactive:

> Use eventReactive to create a calculated value that only updates in
>   response to an event. This is just like a normal reactive expression
>   except it ignores all the usual invalidations that come from its
>   reactive dependencies; it only invalidates in response to the given
>   event.