# R shiny eventReactive button subsets dataframe based on selected checkboxgroup

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

This question extends from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34396403/r-shiny-isolate-reactive-data-frame) that correctly explains how to use a button to subset a dataframe based on a slider.

I need a bit more specific help with my real problem.

I have a function "transition_matrix" in my server.R that takes 2 inputs: (a) a **dataframe** containing product information and (b) a **date**. I pre-load the dataframe as fixed but then allow the user to change the date. So, when the user changes the date, the function executes for the given dataframe and the selected date.

The code thus far:

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  bigmatrix <- reactive({
    transition_matrix(capital_summary_cum, ceiling_date(as.Date(input$datebox),"month")-1)
  })

output$balance_matrix <- renderTable({
    balances_ <- bigmatrix()[1:(default_state +2),] %>%
      round(digits = 0) %>% 
      format(big.mark = ",") 

  transition_matrix <- function(df1, date1){
    date2 <- ceiling_date(as.Date(AddMonths(date1,1)),"month")-days(1)
    ...
    ...
```

What I want to do next is to allow the user to subset the dateframe as well. To do this I offer a group of checkboxes which represent products. So, in addition to the date, the user can also select a subset of products on which to perform the aforementioned function.

The problem is that the function takes approx 1.5 seconds to execute, so each time the user will check a box (of which there are approx 40) the function will be called creating an unwanted 1.5 sec delay.

I rather want to isolate (?) the checkboxes to allow the user to select the desired list of products until a button is clicked. Once the button is clicked I want to subset the dataframe based on the selected checkboxes, and only then feed this into the function. I really would like the date input to remain "fully reactive" so that i don't have to press the button each time the date is also changed.

**How can I add a button that will subset my dataframe based on selected checkboxes and automatically call the function with the selected date?**

Comment: What would happen if you use `eventReactive` instead of `reactive` for your `bigmatrix` function?  Note that you need `input$datebox` as the first argument for `eventReactive`.  If this does not give you the desired outcome, perhaps the checkboxes are inspected somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `isolate` for the checkboxes so that the shiny ignores the update in those.  Shiny will ignore the isolated objects, so it does not refresh the page when they are updated.  I don't see checkboxes in your code, but guess they are somewhere in `transition_matrix` function.

Comment: At this stage I do not know how to add the checkboxes so that they are "isolated" but triggered with a button. Do I add it in the "bigmatrix" reactive function? If so, how do I "trigger" it with a button? Sorry I am really new with R..

Comment: No problem.  The trick is you create an `actionButton` and refers to it within your `bigmatrix` function.  The button does not affect the calculation outcome itself, but by doing so the function is triggered when the button is clicked.

Comment: Thanks Kota, I am not sure but `bigmatrix` is supposed to return a dataset (which is calculated from `transition_matrix` function). I don't believe I can just randomly reference a button in `bigmatrix` because it is expecting a dataset and nothing more? If I am misunderstanding, then how and where exactly do I add a reference to the actionButton?

Comment: You can leave your final output as `data.frame` object.  You can refer to an `actionButton` element just by including that in your function.  For example, suppose your code is `reactive({ input$button; data.frame(x = 1:10)  })`.  Then, this function returns a `data.frame`.  `input$button` does nothing to change the data, but just because this object is there, shiny triggers this reactive function when the button is clicked.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is something similar to what you want to achieve.
Note:

Use `eventReactive` to specify what your app to react to.  In this case, the `get_table` function reacts to the update button and the checkbox for date, while the checkbox for variables does not trigger the function.

For your information, the `actionButton` has a integer value inside and the value increments by one when clicked.  The app detects the changes in the value and trigger the function.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- list(checkboxGroupInput("varbox", "Variable", choices = c("x", "y")),
           br(), br(),
           checkboxGroupInput("datebox", "Date", choices = c("1", "2", "3")),
           br(), br(),
           actionButton("btn", "update"),
           tableOutput("tbl")) 

server <- function(input, output) {

  sub_fun <- function(dates, variables) {
    # sub function to create table
    # this does not have any reactive element inside
    tmp <- data.frame(day = rep(1:3, 4), x = 1:12, y = 13:24)
    tmp[tmp$day %in% dates, c("day", variables), drop = FALSE]
  }

  get_table <- eventReactive({input$btn; input$datebox}, {
    # reactive function to define the configulation
    sub_fun(as.character(input$datebox), input$varbox)
  })  

  output$tbl <- renderTable({
    get_table()
  })
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```